# Webpage display same as code

Tags: html

I'm very new to Javascript and HTML but I wondered if there was a way you could make your webpage display the same way as your code. Such as if you had something like this:

```
<html>
<body>
<input type="button" value="Text">
<b>Hello world               Hello<b>
</body>
</html>
```

Is there some sort of code I can put in to make it display just like that on the webpage. When I try it there aren't that many spaces between the world and Hello.

Comment: I should not tell you that... Try many `&nbsp`... Seriously, you need to read about CSS. Google is you friend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put that in a pre tag

```
<pre>hello           hello</pre>
```

pre tags keep spacing

Comment: Oh ok I'll go try that. I'm sorry if I'm confusing or this is a dumb question.